# Wordpress site on migrating to localhost is giving ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the online wordpress site onto my localhost, I have changed the base url and also made the db connections to locahost but I keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET!

the site is in WordPress 3.4.2

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/err_connection_reset-unknown-error Try turning of this two features in php.ini file :apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64

Comment: but I cant find these two features in php.ini

Comment: ,you can add it,by your own